# Fetch data from two different tables in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

On my webserver there is a database with following two tables:

```
tbl_Friend                                    tbl_Colleague

| id | Name | First name | Place |            | id | Name | First name | Place | 
----------------------------------            ----------------------------------
|  1 | XXXX | XXXXXXXXXX |   1   |            |  1 | AAAA | AAAAAAAAAA |   1   |
|  2 | YYYY | YYYYYYYYYY |   2   |            |  2 | BBBB | BBBBBBBBBB |   3   |
|  3 | ZZZZ | ZZZZZZZZZZ |   1   |            |  3 | CCCC | CCCCCCCCCC |   4   |
```

Now I want to fetch all Persons from `tbl_Friend` and `tbl_Colleague` who live in `place 1`. For that I have to the data from both tables and here is my problem: How can I fetch data from two different tables in only one query? My result should look like this:

```
| id | Name | First name | Place |
----------------------------------
|  1 | XXXX | XXXXXXXXXX |   1   |
|  1 | AAAA | AAAAAAAAAA |   1   |
|  3 | ZZZZ | ZZZZZZZZZZ |   1   |
```

Can I use something like `FROM tbl_Friend | tbl_Colleague` or something else? Or do I have to use a Join for this?

Comment: Try UNION or UNION ALL statment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, Name, First name, Place FROM tbl_Friend
  WHERE Place= 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, Name, First name, Place FROM tbl_Colleague
  WHERE Place= 1
```

Comment: +1. The `UNION ALL` set operator will return *all* matching rows, and doesn't require the extra step of identifying and removing duplicates.   This will return resultset specified by OP, although we notice the rows will be in a different order. OP can add an `ORDER BY` clause if there's a particular sequence he wants the rows. (OP didn't ask this, but in queries like this, I will typically include an additional short discriminator column: a literal in the SELECT list of each query that I can use to identify which query returned the row. `SELECT 'f' AS src, ... UNION ALL SELECT 'c', ...`

Comment: @Cilenco, notice, that your schema doesn't normalized.

Comment: Yes I know. This is just a cutout from my whole table to make it easier here.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

select * from tbl_friend a, tbl_colleague b where a.place = b.place and place like '1';

Comment: correction:select * from tbl_friend a, tbl_colleague b where a.place = b.place and a.place like '1';