# Retrive data from different table in single Mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with three tables (`employee1`, `employee2` and `employee3`). The columns are the same in every table (`slno`, `name`, `dob` and `state`).

I want to retrieve all data from these all tables in a sql query and also retrieve the data where state is `delhi`.

Comment: Do you mean two queries; one for all data, and another for the delhi data? Check out UNION ALL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch data from two different tables in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281450/fetch-data-from-two-different-tables-in-one-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT * FROM Employee1
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM Employee2
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM Employee3
     ) as T
WHERE T.state = 'delhi'
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efdd7/1)

And you probably will be better having a single employee table with an aditional id field

```
TableID   | slno | name | dob  | state
Employee1 |      |      |      |
Employee2 |      |      |      |
Employee3 |      |      |      |
Employee1 |      |      |      |
```

Comment: ERROR: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: I updte the syntaxis, also include a fiddle